# convert username to guid for asp.net validation using 'asp:login'/'SqlMembershipProvider'(membership)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using 'asp:login' tag with 'membership' in web.config file to authenticate users.  Need to query users without using 'asp:login' tag.  Need to be able to convert string username (e.g., 'username') to 'GUID'/'UserId' in database(e.g., '00000000-0000-0000...') in order to do this.  There is a 'Guid.Parse/TryParse' method but that expects it to already be in '00000000-0000-0000...' format.  It appears to be in some kind of Hex format.  Then there is the issue of the password which is obviously encrypted but that is a separate issue.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you have yourself quite confused here.  The username (a string) is a totally different item from the user ID (a GUID).  There is no direct conversion, but you can query the DB to get the user id for a username and vice versa, or use the Membership classes to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(theUserName);
Guid userId = (user == null) ? Guid.Empty : (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
```

The `Guid` ID of the user is stored in [the `ProviderUserKey` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.provideruserkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of [the `MembershipUser` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To retrieve an instance of the `MembershipUser` class for the user with a specific username, you need to use [the static `Membersip.GetUser(username, userIsOnline)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77f10054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Assuming that you're querying for a user other than the current user, passing `false` to the `userIsOnline` parameter ensures that you don't affect the user's last activity time.

Alternatively, if you *are* querying for the current user, you can use [the `Membersip.GetUser()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcxcb339%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will return the `MembershipUser` instance for the user currently logged on.

Comment: @Richard Deeming: Thank you for the quick response.